# model for pure premium using GLM for frequency and severity

Tags: actuarial-science

I want to estimate a model for frequency and for severity in order to obtain a pure premium, defined as frequency by severity.

The frequency is calculated as claim count divided by exposures, this quotient is not necessarily a non-negative integer, but with GLM, frequency can be model with Poisson distribution.

my data are

`year age_category Gender Teritory conteo siniestros exposed upc_millon valor_millon freq
1 2010    0-5       F   Alejada    180         87        75        121          111 0.48
2 2010    0-5       F  Ciudades 103453      76219     40228      60755        84981 0.74
3 2010   6-10       F  Especial   5129       3194      2078       3289         3013 0.62
4 2010    6-10      F    Normal  27393      18436     10735      15656        16692 0.67
5 2010    11-15     M   Alejada    185         98        73        116          110 0.53
6 2010    11-15     M  Ciudades 106915      80731     41719      62991       105135 0.76`

I use the code

`glm(freq~Gender+Teritory+age_category, family = poisson(link=log), data=datos, weight= exposed)`

in R, for modeling frequency. But the model in R gives me an infinite AIC and the warning is

`Warning messages: 1: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 0.480000 Error in cat("1: In dpois(y, mu, log = TRUE) : non-integer x = 0.480000", : argument 2 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have the individual level exposure, count data, or has this been lost?

Comment: it's count data

Comment: But you said "my data for frequency are numbers in the interval (0,1]", which is not count data.  So I'm a bit confused, unfortunately.

Comment: @MatthewDrury I think `freq` is constructed by taking `siniestros` over `conteo`. But at any rate, this question is totally unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dpois` function uses the gamma function to calculate the ancillary statistic $y!$ for integral and non-integral values. But if you inspect the mathematical properties of the gamma, it is very irregular at these values.

You can fit non-integral values in a Poisson GLM without warning if you specify `family=quasipoisson`. But that's beside the point. You've fit your model incorrectly. You are modeling a proportion using a relative risks model. That means you should not use a ratio as an outcome. Rather, model the numerator and use the denominator as an offset. BTW `exposed` is not the denominator, so the weight is wrong. I get the values of `freq` by taking `siniestros / conteo` which input correctly would be:

```
glm(siniestros ~ Gender+Teritory+age_category+ offset(log(conteo)), 
  family = poisson(link=log), data=datos)
```

Comment: then for the severity the model is
`glm(valor_millon~Gender+Teritory+age_category,family = Gamma(link=log),data=datos, weights = siniestros)`
and for the pure premium with the tweedie distribution is
`glm(valor_millon~Gender+Teritory+age_category, data = datos, family = tweedie(var.power = prof$p.max, link.power = 0), weights = conteo)` is this correct?